# How to open Firebase Dynamic Link in Play Store App

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using invitation links from Firebase Dynamic Links that redirect my user to the Play Store on Android if the app is not installed. The redirection works fine and my app's store page is opened.

The problem is that the Play Store is opened in a browser window rather than in the Play Store app. This means that the user will have to type in their password to install the app even though they are already logged in on the device.

How can I get the link to be opened in the Play Store app instead so that the user can install with a single click?

Answer (score 0):

I use [branch.io](https://branch.io) for these type of links (you do not need to install the SDK)

1. Create an account then create new app
2. Click `Configuration` on left menu select 1I have an Android App1
3. Search for your app and select it then fill other options if you like
4. it will give you a link `https://[YOUR_APP_ID ].app.link`
5. use this link instead of store link in firebase dynamic link

They have a way to redirect the link correctly